# Androidmanifest xml does not exist or has incorrect root tag

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After I renamed my `app/src/main` directory to `app/src/bk` using the rename function from Android Studio I get the following error message:

> Androidmanifest xml does not exist or has incorrect root tag

I have already tried all the given answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424135/android-studio-android-manifest-doesnt-exists-or-has-incorrect-root-tag). Unfortunately none of them worked. Also did I checkout an [issue report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65467).

Is there any way to get this working?

The moment I copy the `bk` directory and rename it to `main` the error disappears and I can build the app.

Comment: It seems your Manifest does not reflect the changes you make to your package name. Open your Manifest and replace `main` with `bk` in your package name (only).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Android Manifest doesn't exists or has incorrect root tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424135/android-studio-android-manifest-doesnt-exists-or-has-incorrect-root-tag)

Answer (score 6):

I **solved** this **by re-importing** the project. It automatically *Sync project with Gradle files*. This can also be done by clicking on **Sync project with Gradle files** button in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

***I think its not allowed to rename app/src/main***

The commented thing will never happen because when we sync project with cradle it will replace ***main*** by default

As i change my main to any other the problem came is It cant identify the manifest. 
so i specify the path to manifest in gradle.build.

You can build the project if you add this in your build.gradle under android.

```
sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'src/bk/AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
        }
```

and i got warnings like this.

```
Error:(33, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(24, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
Error:(22, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').
Error:(23, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
```

As from the warnings the app cant find drawables/strings associated with it as we indirectly show path to manifest.

I may be wrong. I am adding my assumptions as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

By changing the name of the folders, the path to your AndroidManifest.xml file changes. You need to make sure, that you are pointing to the correct file in Project Structure -> Modules -> [Correct module] -> Android -> Manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

In My case setting.gradle is empty

in contain

```
include ':app'
```

These line indicates these is app if module than add

```
include ':module_name'(if not present)
```

after that Sync Gradle file using Sync_now or Sync Button

thanks