# Android Studio: unable to create new style resource value

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I'm using Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.14
and I'm facing some weird problems with the AndroidManifest.xml, first of all, seems it doesn't recognize the keys at my local style resource folder:

[image]

though the file and the keys exist there:

[image]

I've already tried to clean and make the project but that didn't helped.
Also, it seems impossible if I try to add a new style as the choose directories error appear in the lower part of the "New Style Value Resource" dialog when I click over OK:

[image]

Clicking over the buttons on the right side of the dialog doesn't help either (+ sign and his button friends) the plus button does absolutely nothing :(
Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:** It seems all the deal was **files weren't in sync with Gradle's**: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424135/android-studio-android-manifest-doesnt-exists-or-has-incorrect-root-tag)