# Can't migrating AndroidManifest.xml file to Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

When i try to `migrating Eclipse ADT project to Android Studio` using "`Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)`" then selecting project root folder and then third window gives me error like this

```
C:\Users\Tsomone\workspace\cims-android-app-new\AndroidManifest.xml:
Invalid XML file: C:\Users\Tsomone\workspace\cims-android-app-new\AndroidManifest.xml:
Premature end of file.
```

and when i try to click Finish, it shows AlertDialog with

"`There are unrecoverable errors which must be corrected first`".

How can i solve this problem?

Happy Coding!

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open project.properties file in a text editor and remove the line which was related to `appcompat`. Then I managed to import the project without errors. After successful import, I added appcompat as a dependency

[Android Studio: Android Manifest doesn't exists or has incorrect root tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424135/android-studio-android-manifest-doesnt-exists-or-has-incorrect-root-tag)

Migrating From Eclipse Projects

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

```
FAQ:
```

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/FAQ+on+Migrating+to+IntelliJ+IDEA