# Code in android manifest file deleted

Tags: android, android-studio

I have never had this problem before, when I opened Android Studio as usual, the code in the manifest file was completly deleted. I don't understand why. I tried closing/reopening android studio and restarting my computer but always the same issue. Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync project with gradle file.

Follow below link : 
[Android Studio: Android Manifest doesn't exists or has incorrect root tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424135/android-studio-android-manifest-doesnt-exists-or-has-incorrect-root-tag)

May help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link but the solutions proposed don't work for me. When I sync with gradle file I got these 2 errors : 

Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\toshiba\AndroidStudioProjects\CreditLeft\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Error:Contenu non autorisé dans le prologue.

Comment: You can copy other projects manifest file. Put it in current project manifest location. Change according to your require module. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes sure I just wanted to do it directly without recoding evereything. Never mind I'll do it anyway it's the only solution

Comment: Actually I solved my problems by clicking right on my android manifest file, then I clicked on "local History"->"show history" and I finally found the code that was deleted !

Comment: Ok great. Also thanks for giving this solution because I don't know this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but because I had a backup on GitHub, I just copied my Android Manifest code from there and pasted it on my project, so I would suggest that you also try to push your project on GitHub to avoid further losing your code.. Hope this will help.