# Getting Exception on creating blank activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am using Android Studio to develop an Android application. I am trying to create a new Activity by right clicking my package name and selecting New > Activity > Blank Activity. Once the create activity dialog comes up, I press finish after entering the details.

At that point the following Exception happens (which I see in terminal) -

> [  41034]  ERROR - .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - Last Action:   [
>   193585]   WARN - ins.android.templates.Template -
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "AndroidManifest.xml.ftl" not
>   found.  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   Template "AndroidManifest.xml.ftl" not found.

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/24824736/1086930 with no success.

System information - 
Android Studio 1.3.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Are you able to see the AndroidManifest.xml file  in your app directory.

Comment: Because the error seems say that missing the Manifest file.

Comment: I can see it in my project explorer. The error seems to be about the missing template of AndroidManifest.

Comment: Android studio version?

Comment: Android Studio 1.3.2

Comment: Actually I try the same in my android studios 1.3 version It is successfully create the blank activity.