# "AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag" Error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to AndroidStudio AND Gradle.

I imported a project from eclipse, created a module, and tried to run the project, but I got this error:

```
AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag
```

I have been looking at this previous solution for it: 
[How to build an android library with Android Studio and gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718026/how-to-build-an-android-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle)

But that solution is WAY too advanced for me.

Could someone please help me understand in simpler terms what is going wrong and how I can fix it?

Thank you!

Update after one of the answers:

These are the options I have under the build menu:

[image]

Comment: did you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424135/android-studio-android-manifest-doesnt-exists-or-has-incorrect-root-tag

Comment: Try sync the gradle files..... it will work

Comment: @Ganesh I did sync and still same problem

Comment: Where is your build.gradle file ?

Answer (score 33):

clicking on Sync project with Gradle files button will solve your problem.

That button is under File section on Android Studio 3.6.1

Comment: Where is that button? :)

Comment: this one:http://i.stack.imgur.com/XuRvN.png, another option is to go like this: Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: so try: Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: I don't have that option....updating my original question with a screenshot of what options I have under build

Answer (score 16):

1. Close your Android Studio
2. Goto `C:\Users\user\.AndroidStudioX.X\system` and **DELETE** the cache
   folder
3. Launch the Android Studio
4. Goto Build (menu) -> Clean Project when done click the
   Build (menu) again and click rebuild project.

That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

For me the issue went away once I opened the android folder of the project in Android Studio to run the project.

So basically, because I was trying to run the Android project from the Root folder, it gave me the error. We need to run the project by selecting the android folder of the project only.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I agree with you. It is small detail but can breaks everything's. Especially wrong named outsource projects.

Answer (score 6):

Click on File > Invalidate Cache/Restart, and that's it. Your project should start working.

Answer (score 3):

For me clicking on Sync project with Gradle files button did not solve the problem alone.

After Syncing project with Gradle files, I explicitly had to invalidate the cache and restart studio. Only after this action, the red cross-mark over configuration disappeared and everything started working.

Comment: File...Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my android project got corrupted and some of the files were showing characters, binary numbers, etc. I tried the following solutions

1. Invalidate & Restart
2. Rebuild Project
3. Sync with Gradle File

But none of the above solutions worked for me.

Then I just deleted the cache folder under `C:\Users\username\.AndroidStudio3.6\system`

and all the invalid characters disappeared and the actual contents of all the files were displayed. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Every Android project needs a file called `AndroidManifest.xml` to tell Android about itself. Either your project doesn't have one, or it's not in the place that Android Studio expects it to be. Try to find it, and move it to the root folder of the project.

Comment: I have that file of course. It is at the root of the project

Comment: In that case, the root tag is not right, or Android Studio can't see it for whatever reason. Can you see it in Android Studio?

Comment: Yes I can see it in Android studio. Where is the root tag and what do you mean by it?

Comment: The opening <> xml tag in the AndroidManifest. There should be something like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <manifest...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.problemio"
    android:versionCode="172"
    android:versionName="2.6.15" >

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the problem, but the package name should be at least three 'words', so try changing it to "com.problemio.something"

Comment: Is this an issue only on AndroidStudio? It was ok on Eclipse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97873/discussion-between-genadinik-and-yedidyak).

Answer (score 1):

1.Check whether the **manifest** file is there or not.

2.If it is there, check whether the **package** name is correct or not..

3.If you project has small number of classes, then you create new project in android and then copy paste your code from eclipse. It will be simple.  But it is recommended only for small project.

And finally click  'Sync' in the Gradle file. Followed by Rebuilding the project will do a trick.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Manifest file seemed to be corrupted or maybe its meta data. Trying to open it in Android Studio will show some characters that you see when opening a binary file with a text editor, for ex. Anyway, my project is under Git, so I just deleted it and restored it back, problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to C drive click User then select your android studio folder then select System find Cache folder and delete this folder before doing this close your android Studio.It will surely work.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, things I tried:

1. I delete user->gradle-> delete cache folder
2. Android studio-> file-> Invalid cache/restart
   Using my problem is get resolved

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, things I tried:

1. Syncing the file with gradle
2. Invalidate/Restart
   But the problem was still there in the manifest folder-> manifest.xml file it had only 1 line.
3. So I went to User-> your_username -> Android Studio v -> caches and Deleted the cache folder.
   Started Android Studio, and my problem was gone.
   But I am not sure which of these might solve yours.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened AndroidManifest.xml in file editor. Add some letters, save it, then android studio found AndroidManifest.
After this I can build project successfully

Answer (score 0):

if your AndroidManifest.xml looks wierd than you can try checking local history or git history. by doing that you can copy paste the previous version AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score -1):

Experienced that too, there is a line on your manifest code that's incorrect, simply go through it and make necessary corrections.