# How to add flurry into android studio project?

Tags: android, flurry

How can I add flurry into my android studio project, I haven't done this before, so I am not entirely sure where to add the files? I have FlurryAnalytics.jar

and how to use in my app?

thanx

Comment: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: yes that's fine thax, but where inside the android studio's gradle build should I add the .jar file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I added Flurry:

- Add FlurryAnalytics_3.3.2.jar (or latest) to libs folder (create this directory if necessary)

  - Add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')` to the dependencies in your project's build.gradle

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
- or Gradle + Jcenter `compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.2.0'`
- Add appropriate permissions to AndroidManifest.xml:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  ```
- Make sure a versionName attribute is specified in AndroidManifest.xml to have data reported under that version name, such as:

  ```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.0">
  ```
- Optionally, add you Flurry API key to a constants file, such as AppConstants.java:

  ```
  public class AppConstants {
      public static final String FLURRY_API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"; // where YOUR_API_KEY  is your actual API key from FLURRY similar to 1ABCDE23EFGH4IJKLMN5O
  ```
- Add the Flurry onStartSession and onEndSession to each activity in your app:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onStart()
  {
      super.onStart();
      FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, AppConstants.FLURRY_API_KEY);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop()
  {
      super.onStop();
      FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
  }
  ```

I still had some issues at this point and selected a hint recommended by Android Studio while viewing my build.gradle file. It changed gradle-1.8-bin.zip to gradle-1.8-bin.zip to gradle-1.8-all.zip in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip
```

After this, my project built successfully and started to log Flurry events. FYI, it takes a few hours to see the logs in Flurry.

This is a good [reference for Android Studio and gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16718026/1623760)

And of course, [Flurry](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Android) provided the details for much of this as well.