# Gradle failed to resolve library in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, libraries

I want to include a library in Android Studio , but it displays error like below :

> "Failed to resolve:com.lemonlab:expandable-button-menu:1.0.0"

How to fix this problem?

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "ayowes.com.newecampus"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-ptimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
        compile 'com.lemonlab:expandable-button-menu:1.0.0'
        compile files('libs/pinchzoom.jar')
    }
```

Comment: where have you inserted the lib and what is the log?

Comment: in gradle , i type compile 'com.lemonlab:expandable-button-menu:1.0.0' , after that i sync and display error "Failed to resolve:com.lemonlab:expandable-button-menu:1.0.0'"

Comment: Show us your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Not sure but try this File -> Invalidate caches/restart-> choose Invalidate caches/restart.

Comment: @yuya raj , i have tried but  not work

Comment: Check this accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118606/gradle-in-android-studio-failed-to-resolve-third-party-libraries

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To be able to use a lib project you need to include it in your application's settings.gradle add:

```
include '..:ExpandableButtonMenu:library'
```

and then in your build.gradle add:

```
compile project(':..:ExpandableButtonMenu:library')
```

place ExpandableButtonMenu project along side your own (same folder)

see this  [How to build an android library with Android Studio and gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718026/how-to-build-an-android-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle) for more details.

Comment: what to do after select lib ?

Comment: sync project with gradle files.

Answer (score 59):

You go File->Settings->Gradle
Look at the "Offline work" inbox, if it's checked u uncheck and try to sync again
I have the same problem and i try this , the problem resolved. Good luck !

Comment: This worked for me as well I don't know why it got checked -_-

Comment: Thanks! If only gradle said "cannot resolve but you are in offline mode if you hadn't realised".

Comment: Exactly. Android Studio has miles to go

Answer (score 55):

I had the same problem, the first thing that came to mind was repositories. So I checked the `build.gradle` file for the whole project and added the following code, then synchronized the gradle with project and problem was solved!

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: this actually is the prescribed solution to most occurrences of the said problem

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Why `allprojects` ?

Answer (score 25):

Some time you may just need to add `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` in your allprojects block in project level build.gradle file.

Example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me...

Answer (score 6):

Solved by using "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" instead of "https://jcenter.bintray.com/".

```
repositories {
    jcenter( { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" } )
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's `co.lemonlabs`, you have a typo in your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'co.lemonlabs:expandable-button-menu:1.0.0'
```

Source: https://github.com/lemonlabs/ExpandableButtonMenu#including-in-your-project

Answer (score 5):

Check to see if your gradle is offline. Preferences-ProjectSettings-Gradle.
If you're trying to add a library while offline, you'll see that error. Also, try Build-Clean, it may provide you with more detail.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

1. Clean project
2. Invalidate cache and restart studio
3. Check android **SDK** path is proper
4. Check is there any error in any of your resource file

Comment: After an hour of trying everything I could think of, a simple restart solved the problem. Sometimes I hate Android Studio....

Comment: @Apfelsaft Restart the PC? or AS itself? What is your OS?

Answer (score 2):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I added this in build.gradle, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing this error and fixed by adding this in my settings.gradle

**Groovy**

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

under `dependencyResolutionManagement`

**Kotlin Scripts**

```
maven { setUrl( "https://jitpack.io") }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, i added the following lines in build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/dev-fingerlinks/maven'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me follwing steps helped.

It seems to be bug of Android Studio 3.4/3.5 and it was "fixed" by disabling:

**File → Settings → Experimental → Gradle → Only sync the active variant**

Answer (score 0):

If adding repositories didn't work, check that your settings.gradle contains:

```
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

My reason for this type of error was requesting a non-existent release.  Verify your names and version numbers.  As noted by lamat8: Any error in your build files can cause this.