# Gradle in Android Studio: Failed to resolve third-party libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have been trying to switch my project from Intellij to Android Studio, which has required me to create a build.gradle file. I know I can add each of these as a library dependency, but I ideally want to be able to get the maven repository dependency working.

Every time I sync, my support libraries are synced fine, but for each third-party library, I get something like

> "Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1"

for each library.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

// Google Play Services
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

// Support Libraries
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'

// third-party libraries
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.9.24'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
compile 'com.github.markushi:android-ui:1.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2'
compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.2'

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add:

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
```

to the `build.gradle`. Now you have `repositories` defined only in build script which resolves dependencies only for the `buildscript` itself not for the project.

Comment: I too faced the same problem but I had to disable "work offline" option in gradle settings of Android Studio to make it work. Just adding it here so that if anyone else faces my issue can benefit from it.

Comment: Just to clarify: This block of code needs to be added to the `allprojects` block of the highest level `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 10):

Just to share infomation, I got same problem and the solution was different.

In my case, proxy server was used and it causes the problem. I needed to [configure https proxy settings](http://corochann.com/gradle-sync-fails-in-android-studio-1-3-300.html), as discussed in [gradle behind proxy in Android Studio 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803610/gradle-behind-proxy-in-android-studio-1-3).

Comment: Had the same issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

If you use `VPN` | `Proxy` on your system then use your proxy info in the `gradle.properties` file in your project like the following lines of code:

```
# HTTP Proxy
systemProp.http.proxyHost={Host Address}
systemProp.http.proxyPort={Port Number}
systemProp.http.proxyUser={Proxy Username}
systemProp.http.proxyPassword={Proxy Password}
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts={NonProxy Hosts Address} # like: 127.0.0.1,localhost

# HTTPS Proxy
systemProp.https.proxyHost={Host Address}
systemProp.https.proxyPort={Port Number}
systemProp.https.proxyUser={Proxy Username}
systemProp.https.proxyPassword={Proxy Password}
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts={NonProxy Hosts Address} # like: 127.0.0.1,localhost
```

Now just replace `{.....}` in the above code with appropriate data

---

Also you can set Android studio proxies like the following image by your proxy info in `File>Settings`:

[image]

Now test again...!

Answer (score 1):

```
repositories {
jcenter {
    url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
}
```

// mavenCentral()
}

Answer (score 1):

this helps

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

in projects's gradle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well , if your network connection is fine(wheter using proxy | VPNs or not), simply just try `turn off'offline mode' and sync` when using android studio with `gradle 2.3`,this worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the settings do not currently work with new Android updates, so the solution currently is to add this section to buuild.Gradle(Project:)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
    }
}

******************************************
// Add this section if it does not exist  
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
******************************************


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

**********************************************
// Add this section if it does not exist
gradlePluginPortal()
**********************************************

  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```