# Unable to add Facebook SDK as a dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, facebook-sdk-4.0

This is the error I am getting:

**Error:(14, 13) Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0 Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog**

I can see in the Gradle console that it is looking for the lib in the local SDK library, although I made sure that the Work Offline checkbox in the gradle settings is unchecked.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Any ideas what can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to do this in build.grade of application level

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
```

and this one in build.grade at app level folder

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Aakash, thanks for assisting.

Can you elaborate on what is the build.gradle in the app level folder and what is the application level?

Comment: check in your project structure you will find two build.gradle files, one is at the application level and another one is in the app folder, thats what i meant by application and app level

Comment: in my project there is only one build.gradle which is located in the app folder.
Where should I find the other one?

Comment: on the application level, can you post screenshot of your project structure so that i can explain

Comment: double click on the project icon on top or right click on project and open module settings and try to check over there

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing there. I see that i do not have the app folder in my project. is there a way to add it?

Comment: try to check in workspace in folder view instead of studio, you may find it

Answer (score 0):

Was searching for this same problem and the below answer got me thinking, because I always use Charles Proxy while developing, and at the moment it wasn't running. When I launched it again, it started working with the initial settings.

> Just to share infomation, I got same problem and the solution was
>   different.
>
> In my case, proxy server was used and it causes the problem. I needed
>   to configure https proxy settings, as discussed in gradle behind proxy
>   in Android Studio 1.3.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31944055/1967951)