# Android Studio Error: Failed to Resolve.. <Library name>

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to implement the gradle:

```
compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.2'
```

..in my project and I keep getting an error when the Gradle is building. The error I get is:

> Error:(36, 13) Failed to resolve: com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.2

That's all it displays and it doesn't even display a reason. I referred to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118606/gradle-in-android-studio-failed-to-resolve-third-party-libraries) answer as well, but the error persists. Why does this error normally occur?

**EDIT:**

**My build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**EDIT:**

**App module**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.2'
}
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'`

**build.gradle**

```
    repositories 
   {
    mavenCentral()
    }

dependencies {
  compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync`** Your Project .

Comment: The 1.0.1 version has some bugs. I need the latest version :)

Comment: Btw which section should I add the mavenCentral() code line? There's two repositories in my gradle. One in the buildscript and another in the allprojects

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'`

Comment: Because of this (https://github.com/edmodo/cropper/issues/21) issue, I need the 1.0.2. They say they have fixed it in the 1.0.2 version

Comment: @Earthling post your app module `build.gradle`

Comment: Which section should I add the mavenCentral() code line? There's two repositories in my gradle. One in the buildscript and another in the allprojects?

Comment: Edited the App Module

Comment: @Earthling Glad to help .

Answer (score 0):

With Gradle 2.2.2, add following into projectname.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
```