# Failed to resolve Gradle Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, resolve

I want to add some third-party libraries, but I always got the "Failed to resolve" error.
I tried some suggestions I found here, like:
[Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12) , 
[Gradle failed to resolve library in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493470/gradle-failed-to-resolve-library-in-android-studio)
and [Gradle in Android Studio: Failed to resolve third-party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118606/gradle-in-android-studio-failed-to-resolve-third-party-libraries)
but it didn't work! how can I solve the problem? thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: show log message here and gradle file

Answer (score 1):

You should check your gradle files and write down mavenLocal() at the build.gradle(Project: your project name)

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

libraries which you want to add are at maven or at any other repository, you need to add repository. so that gradle can download library from that repository.

let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I added to Gradle
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    } But still get the error

Comment: this library is not supported on android studio, use its jar file.

Comment: also this library is deprecated, no more support, you may use google official API.

Answer (score -1):

mavenCentral();
just add ";".I solve it by this way.