# Fail to resolve third-party libraries

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I download a Android Studio project from https://github.com/chenyangcun/MaterialDesignExample . I add it to my Android Studio and run it,but there occurs some errors:
[image]

The blew is the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aswifter.materialexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.7'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.6.0'
}
```

And then I build a whole new Android project with the same "third-party libraries"
The blew is my bulid.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mummyding.app.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.7'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.6.0'
}
```

What confuses me is the "error info":

[image]

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0' is okay in this project!!!
so my questions:

1. Can you run [this](https://github.com/chenyangcun/MaterialDesignExample) project in your Andorid Studio?
2. Why the "error info"  different?
3. How to fix it?

PS:
Gradle Version : 2.2.1
IDE: Android Studio 1.2.1.1
OS: Ubuntu 15.04
I am in China but I have got a router with shadowsocks (which means I can visit any website I want)
It really confuse me for a long time,so any suggestion will be highly appreciated,thank you advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it!!!!
It's not caused by GFW .It works well when I replaced OpenJDK with Oracle-JDK on my ubuntu!

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be your proxy settings. You may need to set the following in `gradle.properties` (please modify according to your proxy settings):

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8123
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8123
```

Comment: Do you mean File->Settings->System Settings->Http Proxy ? If so,I checked  "No proxy" option(Default Settings ). And I don't see any line like systemProp.http. in   my gradle.properties. Moreover,I don't know how to "modify according to my proxy settings". I am sorry for that I have no knowledge with proxy.

Comment: And I  simply add the lines:'systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8123
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8123' ,but it didn't make any difference

Comment: Since you mentioned shadowsocks (and you can access google etc in browser?) you may already have some proxy setup in your browser.  Please check if you have any proxy settings in your web browser configuration.

Comment: Not yet,I config it in my router,I don't need do anything in my PC.I can visit Google etc with my cell phone/PC if they connect to my wifi.

Comment: Perhaps you have a transparent proxy? Please comment out the lines you added in gradle.properties first.  Just for sure, check if you set gradle to offline mode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493470/gradle-failed-to-resolve-library-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Please try this with sudo

```
dnf install python3-m2crypto
```

https://fedora.pkgs.org/35/fedora-x86_64/python3-m2crypto-0.38.0-2.fc35.x86_64.rpm.html