# How to make an ExpandableListView with 3 TextViews in parent and child lists?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I need to make an `ExpandableListView` with 3 `TextView`s in parent and child lists. I have `parentlist` and `childlist` with 3 `TextView`s in each line. So what should I do next?

```
ArrayList<Contact> list = new ArrayList<>(); //main_equip
    list.add(new Contact("Surdialx", "Status","Available Works"));
    list.add(new Contact("Surdial", "Status","Available Works"));
    list.add(new Contact("Surdialx", "Status","Available Works"));
    list.add(new Contact("Surdial", "Status","Available Works"));
    list.add(new Contact("Surdialx", "Status","Available Works"));
    list.add(new Contact("Surdial", "Status","Available Works"));
    ArrayList<Contact1> childlist = new ArrayList<>(); //eq_works
    childlist.add(new Contact1("Work №1", "Status", "Priority"));
    childlist.add(new Contact1("Work №2", "Status","Priority"));
    childlist.add(new Contact1("Work №3", "Status","Priority"));
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create [Expandable Recyclerview](https://github.com/anandbose/ExpandableListViewDemo) try this way

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        List<ExpandableListAdapter.Item> data = new ArrayList<>();

        data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.HEADER, "Fruits"));
        data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Apple"));
        data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Orange"));
        data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Banana"));
        data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.HEADER, "Cars"));
        data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Audi"));
        data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Aston Martin"));
        data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "BMW"));
        data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Cadillac"));

        ExpandableListAdapter.Item places = new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.HEADER, "Places");
        places.invisibleChildren = new ArrayList<>();
        places.invisibleChildren.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Kerala"));
        places.invisibleChildren.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Tamil Nadu"));
        places.invisibleChildren.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Karnataka"));
        places.invisibleChildren.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Maharashtra"));

        data.add(places);

        recyclerview.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: What libraries must we import to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it with this [library](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter), there is a full example [here](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/Example4Fragment.java).

Basically you group your items into sections:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String header;
    List<Contact> list;
    boolean expanded = true;

    public MySection(String header, List<Contact> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);
        this.myHeader = header;
        this.myList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return expanded? list.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new HeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        final HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;

        headerHolder.tvTitle.setText(title);

        headerHolder.rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                expanded = !expanded;
                headerHolder.imgArrow.setImageResource(
                        expanded ? R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_18dp : R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_18dp
                );
                sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    }
}
```

Then create instance of your sections and set up your adapter:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Add your Sections
sectionAdapter.addSection(new MySection("Surdial", surdialList);
sectionAdapter.addSection(new MySection("Surdialx", surdialXList);
sectionAdapter.addSection(new MySection("Work", workList);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

Comment: import io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter.SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter;
import io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter.StatelessSection;

Comment: have you added the dependencies to your build.gradle?

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'
}

Comment: added the dependencies, but nothing has changed. And one more question: is any library for recyclerview?

Comment: did you click on "Sync now" after adding the dependencies? did the "Sync now" fail?

Comment: "Sync now" helped me with RecyclerView, but he refused to compile io.guthub.luizgrp etc.

Comment: did you add the library dependency in the correct build.gradle file? you shouldn't add it in the top level build file

Comment: check if you have jcenter added in repositories http://stackoverflow.com/a/32873663/1401164