# Failed to resolved : compile 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPicker:v1.0.10'?

Tags: android, android-studio, properties, dependencies, dependency-properties

I am trying to add a third party library in gradle. It is showing Failed to resolve:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPicker:v1.0.10'


    //compile 'gun0912.ted:tedbottompicker:1.0.12'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle failed to resolve library in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493470/gradle-failed-to-resolve-library-in-android-studio)

Comment: I do not recommend that library, as it depends upon a discontinued library (`cwac-camera`) that I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}
```

To your repositories as it's said on [library page](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPicker)?

Answer (score 0):

change

maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }

to

maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }

in app level build.gradle