# Gradle fail to sync

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using this library [Here is a link](https://github.com/halilozercan/bettervideoplayer)
I have already tried this link to solve the problem [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493470/gradle-failed-to-resolve-library-in-android-studio) But in vain....
But still problem is existing in gradle sync...
[image: Error of picture]

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a closer look at the first [link](https://github.com/halilozercan/bettervideoplayer#gradle-dependency) you provided. Here is a snippet from the readme of what you need to do:

> Add this to your app/build.gradle repositories:
>
> `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your app/build.gradle repositories:

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

After that you should have like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

android {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for response.. But still problem :(

Comment: @BilalMustafa Could you post your app/build.gradle?

Comment: @BilalMustafa Try to change from `url 'jitpack.io';` to `url 'https://jitpack.io'`