# Room database in android Failed to resolve 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-room

I want to use Room DB but when I add dependencies the gradle has an error.

> Failed to resolve 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'

I have an image of the error:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28711776/4585226

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your project build.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:
you have to update: Gradle version, Gradle plugin and the last library version