# kotlin not supporting Socket IO in android

Tags: android, socket.io, kotlin

I have two questions

1)My Project contain `dagger2,retofit2,kotlin v1.0.21,rxJava2,OkHttp3` i want to implement `SocketIO` on my project how should i implement?

2) I try to several way but unable to connect `socketIO` so i try to sample code below given code but still unable to connect socket.. please help thanx in advance

```
 package com.easymakers.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import io.socket.client.IO
import io.socket.client.Socket
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var socket : Socket? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->

            connect(view)
         //   connect1()
        }
    }

     private fun connect(view : View) {
         val opts = IO.Options()
         opts.port= 5000
         opts.reconnection = false
        // opts.query =
         socket = IO.socket("https://192.170.1.21",opts)
        socket?.connect()
                ?.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Socket connected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show()
                })
                ?.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, { println("disconnected") })
    }

    private fun connect1(){
        val sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
        sc.init(null, null, null)
        val opts = IO.Options()
        opts.port = 3000
        opts.secure = true
        opts.forceNew = true
        opts.reconnection = true
        val  socket = IO.socket("https://103.69.190.10",opts)
        socket.on("connection", Emitter.Listener {
            println("Connected")
            socket.emit("foo", "hi")
            socket.disconnect()
        }).on("event", Emitter.Listener { }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, Emitter.Listener { })
        socket.connect()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used this library [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/)

With this code it was enough on method OnCreate. Even with an authentication token, but it's optional.

```
val opts = IO.Options()
    opts.query = "token=XXXXXXXXX"
    var socket = IO.socket("https://MYSERVERSOCKET.com", opts)

    socket?.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, {
          Log.d("","==============================CONNECTED")
    })?.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, {
          Log.d("","==============================OFF")
    })
```

Start the connection

```
btnFindNext.setOnClickListener{
        socket.connect()
}
```

and an example of emit

```
btnOtro.setOnClickListener{

        val obj = JSONObject()
        obj.put("var1", "5ab0a8931522f51fac37f5a1")
        obj.put("var2", "91.8392894")
        obj.put("var3", "-93.8392894")

        socket.emit("SendData", obj)
    }
```

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Answer (score 2):

1.1) https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

**Gradle**

Add it as a gradle dependency for Android Studio, in build.gradle:

```
compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
  // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
  exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

> Socket.IO Server 1.x suppport
>
> The current version of socket.io-client-java doesn't support socket.io
>   server 1.x. Please use socket.io-client-java 0.9.x for that instead.

1.2) in github you may see: [image]
this link follow you to the updated version which support 1.x and upper server versions.
link: http://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/project-summary.html

it have next dependency:

```
compile 'io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

2) https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Next step you must start node.js server

> Integrating Socket.IO is composed of two parts:
>
> 1) A server that integrates with (or mounts on) the Node.JS HTTP Server:
>   socket.io
>
> 2) A client library that loads on the browser side:
>   socket.io-client During development, socket.io serves the client
>   automatically for us, as we’ll see, so for now we only have to install
>   one module:

```
npm install --save socket.io
```

Comment: using that only... forget to add over here

Comment: Thanx for replay we successfully implemented this into web, (no issue with nodejs) problem with Android only , i think this issue come in iOS.. do u have different approach ? or i doing something wrong

Comment: We have already implemented socket.io on NodeJS server express app & also referenced socket.io in our web project. And able to connect server socket. But when we use same approach as kotlin socket.io client to connect server socket.io, no connection is establishing between client & server. Not even connect event firing on server side.

Comment: what version of socket.io do you have on server and in client?

Comment: @Rupesh, i am answer about versions because "The current version of socket.io-client-java doesn't support socket.io server 1.x. Please use socket.io-client-java 0.9.x for that instead."

Comment: Android Client side we are using 'io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0'   Sever side  "socket.io": "^2.0.3"  , Web client used 2.1.2

Comment: @Rupesh, i am asking, i am sorry, not answer)

Comment: @Rupesh, i am found new version of socket.io client, pls check: http://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/project-info.html
so in this version in gradle use: compile 'io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

Comment: i try this version but sill facing this issueError:(33, 20) Failed to resolve: io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
<a href="openFile:D:/WorkingCopy/MyApplication/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>     add plugin mavenCentral()

Comment: @Rupesh, add firstly in application's settings.gradle such a: 

"include 'io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'" and then: "compile project('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT') " OR add this "repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}"

Comment: i am sorry to bother u, but i already add this into build.gradle  , how we suppose to add into setting.gradle

Comment: @Rupesh, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718026/how-to-build-an-android-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493470/gradle-failed-to-resolve-library-in-android-studio

Comment: not working , if u have Sample code in kotlin please do share

Comment: same issue  io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT this will not working  mavenCental() and even with particular repository download URL also...

Comment: please upload your build.gradle and full error message