# Error:Failed to resolve: Crosswalk

Tags: android, crosswalk

I'm trying to make a `SDK` using [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android.html). So first I started to make a sample app using
`compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4'`. And it works. Then I tried to make a `SDK` using this. But it didn't work as I expected.

**gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Here is the screenshot of error message

[image]

Comment: can you share gradle file code?

Comment: `samplesdk` module ??

Comment: @Darsh added gradle file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28711776/3348373

Comment: already `Offline work` checkbox is unchecked