# Android Studio Wikitude Native SDK Issue

Tags: android-studio, gradle, native, wikitude, wikitude-sdk

So im trying to first build a basic app using android studio and Wikitudes Native SDK to make an AR app. After following the setup instructions ive ran into an error I cant seem to solve but have an idea of why/where its happening. Does anyone know what could be causing these errors?

[This image here shows the errors I am getting and what looks to be an issue with a few of the imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWxxl.jpg)

Here is also a copy of my build.gradle file (Module: app), and my build.gradle file (Module: NativeSDKExamples), respectively:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion commonCompileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion commonBuildToolsVersion
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.uhg.ent.mobile.lifesciences.amplify"
    minSdkVersion commonMinSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion commonTargetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "7.2.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable true
    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each  { output ->
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
            def fileName = "app-" + variant.buildType.name + ".apk"
            output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
        }
    }
}

flavorDimensions "arch"

productFlavors {
    arm7 {
        dimension "arch"
    }
    arm8 {
        dimension "arch"
    }
    x86 {
        dimension "arch"
    }
    allarchs {
        dimension "arch"
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile (name: 'wikitude-native-sdk', ext:'aar')

arm7Compile project(path: ':plugins', configuration: 'arm7Release')
arm8Compile project(path: ':plugins', configuration: 'arm8Release')
x86Compile project(path: ':plugins', configuration: 'x86Release')
allarchsCompile project(path: ':plugins', configuration: 'allarchsRelease')

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$commonSupportLibVersion"
compile "com.android.support:design:$commonSupportLibVersion"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$commonSupportLibVersion"
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.5'

}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
}
```

AND

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

subprojects {
ext.commonCompileSdkVersion = 26
ext.commonBuildToolsVersion = "26.0.0"
ext.commonMinSdkVersion = 19
ext.commonTargetSdkVersion = 26
ext.commonSupportLibVersion = "26.0.0"
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I believe it may have to deal with dependencies in my grade file but am not sure

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28711776/4475937?

Comment: I did not, but I figured out the issue. I needed an older version of the NDK then everything worked perfectly..there was just no documentation saying to revert to an older version