# integrating robelectric in my project

Tags: android, unit-testing

hello im using android studio and i want to integrate roboelectric here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        ///////////
        applicationId "com.inducesmile.androidmapdrawroute"
        ///////////////
        applicationId "com.application.zarbagaskazay.colivoiturage"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }


}

dependencies {

    ///////////////////////firebase//////////
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    ///////////////////
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    implementation "com.github.danielnilsson9:color-picker-view:1.4.0@aar"
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'

    ////////// google directions //////////////////////////////// google directions //////////////////////
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    ///////////////////////// card view ////////////////
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0-alpha-2'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

heree is my error of build

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0-alpha-2.
```

Open File
Show Details[image]

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0-alpha-2.
Open File
Show Details

[image]

Comment: Can you post your project-level build.gradle?

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean by level build gradle

Comment: @Sub6Resources .

Comment: The project-level build.gradle is stored in the root folder rather than the `app` folder. But I don't think it's the issue, check out my answer @Zarbag Mohamed Elmehdi

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load a snapshot version. You probably want the release version.

**Simply change the `testImplementation` line to:**

```
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'
```

---

If you know what you're doing and are sure you want to use the snapshot version (which is potentially unstable and not recommended unless absolutely necessary) you'll have to add a couple more things.

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0-alpha-3-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

Comment: even with using the 3.8 version im having the same error

Comment: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8.

Comment: and  Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8.

Comment: Okay, we will need to see your project-level `build.gradle` then. (If you are in Android Studio it says `build.gradle (Project: ...)` under the `Gradle Scripts` folder.)

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {

Comment: Could you add it to your original question by editing it (just to make it more readable)

Comment: the post was edited :D and what you want to see was added! thanks for your ime

Comment: Hmm, it looks alright. Not related, but do you mean to have two `applicationId` lines in your app build.gradle?

Comment: the second appid just stayed there when iwas copying some implementaion i deleted it's not related

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings in your app build.gradle in android studio?

Comment: there no red warning just few yellow notification of new librairies

Comment: and the build is done succefully if you delete robotelectric codes

Comment: I've copied your build.gradle exactly to a project of mine and it is compiling just fine. Try running a clean build (`Build` -> `Clean Project` in Android Studio) and syncing again.

Comment: problem persists is there any thing like roboelectrics thanks you another time for your precious time

Comment: One last thing to try. Make sure you have an internet connection and follow the instructions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28711776/6243324 (Other answers on that page may help as well)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173683/discussion-between-sub-6-resources-and-zarbag-mohamed-elmehdi).

Answer (score 0):

In my case **gradle offline mode was enable**

Be sure to disable gradle offline mode in settings. Steps to disable gradle offline mode

1. Go to File > Settings
2. Select **Gradle** under **Build, Execution & Deployment*
3. Uncheck **Offline work** under Global Gradle Settings
4. Click **Apply** button

In offline mode gradle will not download library and will give same error even if you are connected to internet.