# Android Studio. Error: (24, 24) failed to resolve

Tags: android, android-studio

I am taking Coursera Programming Mobile Applications for Android handheld systems course and when I try to run labs I get the error:

> (24, 24): failed to resolve:
>   com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.3.1

My system is using a `Proxi`, but I adjust AS so updates and component are available. What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: post the build.gradle file code!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use a lib project you need to include it in your application's settings.gradle add:

```
include '..:ExpandableButtonMenu:library'
compile project(':..:ExpandableButtonMenu:library')
```

[Good link visit "how to build an android library with android studio and gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718026/how-to-build-an-android-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle)