# How to compile Android native library with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio

I am a new user of android studio and I am developing application based on native library(JNI) and eclipse is provide builder facilities for NDK-build. so any functionality available in android studio to build NDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NDK integration is very basic, limited, and not documented (per the [New Build System page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)) at the time of this writing. There a couple of examples in the samples at the bottom of that page that illustrate how this can be done. You can also check the [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) periodically to see if any additional documentation is available.

Comment: ndk-build is now integrated with Android studio gradle builds. This is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio runs ndk-build automatically if you have a jni directory in your project root. I describe the minimal setup you need in [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667903/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk/24083451#24083451).