# Getting error --> "Execution failed for task" >NDK not configured

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to compile my code on android studio and I am stuck at this point. I don't have any thing to compile using the ndk but everytime the compilation fails with this error.

When I check the workspace.xml it contains ExternalTaskPojo for compileDebugNdk and compileReleaseNdk.

I don't need them but can't figure out a way to remove them as it is an auto generated file.

Please suggest.

Edit -> build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 9
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile project(':a')
compile project(':b')
compile project(':c')
compile project(':d')
compile project(':e')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Another build.gradle file

```
   apply plugin: 'android'

   android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 9


}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-    rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile project(':a')
compile project(':facebookSDK')
compile project(':b')
compile project(':c')
compile project(':d')
compile project(':volley')
compile project(':e')
compile project(':volley')
compile project(':f')
compile project(':g')
compile project(':h')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/AF-Android-SDK-v1.3.16.0.jar')
compile files('libs/lib1')
compile files('libs/lib2')
compile files('libs/lib3')
compile files('libs/lib4')
compile files('libs/FlurryAgent.jar')
compile files('libs/renderscript-v8.jar')
compile files('libs/lib5')
}
```

Comment: is your project is ready made? or created by you?

Comment: I am porting the project from eclipse

Comment: in that project at any place some functionality is use NDK

Comment: I don't use NDK although I have some native libraries in my project (.so)

Comment: look t the answer from reactive-core http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674650/how-to-configure-ndk-with-android-gradle-plugin-0-7

Comment: @goonerdroid - That answer explains how to use pre built libraries and compiling using NDK. I have removed all the native libraries but still when I compile it seems to launch the compileDebugNdk target which gives error. How to stop that?

Comment: okay post your gradle files

Comment: Updated the question with the gradle files.Please check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After sometime I was able to fix my problem. I disabled the ndk-build by adding below property in the build.gradle file.

```
sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
```

Comment: android-gpuimage project runs after removing this line `jni.srcDirs = ['jni']` from library gradle file.