# Oculus Mobile SDK sample project error when I try to build :compileReleaseNdk:

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, oculus, gear-vr

I encountered some errors below when I try to build sample project of oculus mobile sdk.

---

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '~/oculus_sdk/ovr_sdk_mobile_1.0.0.1/VrSamples/Native/CinemaSDK/Projects/Android/build.gradle' line: 28
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':VrSamples:Native:CinemaSDK:Projects:Android'.

  > Could not get unknown property 'compileReleaseNdk' for project ':VrSamples:Native:CinemaSDK:Projects:Android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

---

Someone can fix this problem?

My dev environment is below.

- Android studio 2.2
- Android NDK : android-ndk-r12b
- Oculus Mobile SDK : 1.0.0.1
- OSX 10.11.6

And gradle file content that mentioned in Debug message was like this...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile name: 'VrAppFramework', ext: 'aar'
    compile project(':VrAppSupport:SystemUtils:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt')
    compile project(':VrAppSupport:VrGUI:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt')
    compile project(':VrAppSupport:VrLocale:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt')
    compile project(':VrAppSupport:VrSound:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['../../assets']
        }
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
  compileDebugNdk.dependsOn   'NDKBuildDebug'
  compileReleaseNdk.dependsOn 'NDKBuildRelease'
  clean.dependsOn             'NDKBuildClean'
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def alignedOutputFile = output.outputFile
            def unalignedOutputFile = output.packageApplication.outputFile
            def buildTypeName = variant.buildType.name

            def finalFileName = rootProject.name + "-" + buildTypeName + ".apk"
            def unAlignedFileName = rootProject.name + "-" + buildTypeName + "-unsigned" + ".apk"

            output.packageApplication.outputFile = 
                    new File(unalignedOutputFile.parent, unAlignedFileName)

            if (output.zipAlign) {
                output.outputFile = 
                    new File(alignedOutputFile.parent, finalFileName)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to disable ndk build using answer from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271394/getting-error-execution-failed-for-task-ndk-not-configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found a nice answer on similar issue:
[execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk' failed to run this command ndk-build.cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453085/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugndk-failed-to-run-this-command-ndk)

> `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.`
>
> means that the gradle android plugin is trying to call ndk-build
>   itself to compile your sources. You should get more details than the
>   error code in your log window.
>
> Anyway, currently it does this using an auto-generated Makefile and
>   ignores yours, which can't work since you need to integrate ffmpeg.
>
> To overcome this, you should disable the plugin's automatic ndk
>   integration and make it use the standard *libs* location to get your
>   .so files:
>
> ```
> sourceSets.main {
>     jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
>     jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
> }
> ```
>
> from there you can call *ndk-build* yourself, or make gradle call it
>   for you:
>
> ```
> import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
>
> // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
> task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
>     if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
>         commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
>     } else {
>         commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
>     }
> }
>
> tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
>     compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
> }
> ```
>
> For more information on why all this, you can check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ph0b/9e59058ac59cac104398) and
>   my [blog post](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/).

All you need to do is to **disable the ndk-build** by adding below property in the build.gradle file.

```
sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
```

or remove the second line: `jni.srcDirs = [...]`

Hope it will help