# How to include .so file from Different Project Libraries?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gradle

I am running the project with based on Two library projects which have `libs/armeabi folders` with corresponding .so files. But when I am running the project, it compiles one .so files and other .so is file not correclty pointed. So I am getting UnsatifiedLinkError.

This is project structure:

1. LibProjectA

   +libs/armeabi/a.so
2. LibLibProjectB

   +libs/armeabi/b.so
3. MainProject

   - it loads `a.so` file successfully
   - but failes to load `b.so` file

It does works when I copy the a.so file as `LibLibProjectB/libs/armeabi/a.so`

Can you please anyone help me on this issue ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In your Android.mk you can add these lines for each library you want to add :

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := a_prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := 3rdparty/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/a.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And then, to your final module, add the following :

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := a_prebuilt b_prebuilt
```

Hope it's help you !

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea to implement this in gradle?

Comment: You can do this with a simple search on Google. Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674650/how-to-configure-ndk-with-android-gradle-plugin-0-7).