# Switch Application.mk file based on Android buildType in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

In my project I'm building a NDK-library with gradle, and need to find a way to use different `Application.mk` files based on the android `buildType` in gradle.

(The different make-files are necessary to include some preprocessor macros and other compiler flags.)

I tried to set the make-file in a project propery in the gradle build according to the build type, and use this property in my custom ndk-build task.

Unfortunately, always the last make-file is used, independently of the `buildVariant` (if the order of build types is `release` - `debug` the debug file, and if the order is `debug` - `release` the release file)

This is the android buildType:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        project.ext.set("makefile", "Application_release.mk");
        ...
    }
    debug{
        project.ext.set("makefile", "Application_debug.mk");
        ...
    }

}
```

And this is the ndk-task:

```
task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    println "buildNative $project.makefile"
    def ndkDir = android.plugin.ndkFolder
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
        '-C', file('jni').absolutePath,
        '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
        "NDK_APPLICATION_MK=$project.makefile",
        'V=1'
}
```

I'm not really familiar with gradle, so there might be an easy solution to this that I just couldn't find yet.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878689/android-ndk-and-gradle-different-android-mk-per-build-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not as easy as you seem to think. Personally, 
I did it by creating a separate task for each build and assigning it the respective compilation task.

For example:

```
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
task ndkBuildDebug(type: Exec) {
    println "buildNative $project.makefile"
    def ndkDir = android.plugin.ndkFolder

    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            '-C', file('jni').absolutePath,
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
            "NDK_APPLICATION_MK=Application_debug.mk",
            'V=1'
}

//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
task ndkBuildRelease(type: Exec) {
    println "buildNative $project.makefile"
    def ndkDir = android.plugin.ndkFolder

    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            '-C', file('jni').absolutePath,
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
            "NDK_APPLICATION_MK=Application_release.mk",
            'V=1'
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'compileDebugJava') {
        task.dependsOn ndkBuildDebug
    } else if (task.name == 'compileReleaseJava') {
        task.dependsOn ndkBuildRelease
    }
}
```

If there are better ways to do it, I would love to hear them but for now this works for me.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helps. I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: If there are no changes inside your sources, ndk-build will not rebuild these even when a different Application.mk file is choosen. I've written another solution to a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878689/android-ndk-and-gradle-different-android-mk-per-build-type#29081388

Comment: @ph0b if you want to force a rebuild you can simply invoke ndk-build with -B flag.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do in my solution. My point is to make it automatically since it's easy to forget to trigger a rebuild when switching buildType.