# How to use the gradle variables in Android.mk?

Tags: android, git, opencv, android-gradle-plugin

Please, I would like to know how to use a variable defined from the gradle in the Android.mk file or is there anyway to pass some variable from gradle to Android.mk?

I know this is a question that seems a weird, but I tried a lot of possibity and it did not work.

Indeed, I'm working on a collaborative project with classmates and we use OpenCV and other type of library. The problem is that most of these libraries have paths that vary according to developer's computer. So, since we're using git, there are constant conflicts in these files.

To solve the problem, I first use the environment variables in the file `/etc/profile.d/my_proj.sh`, and it did not work. So I created a properties file in which I put all these paths and I wrote a function to read the file and get those values in the build.gradle file. Now I would like to know how to share those variable with the `Android.mk` file.

Here I'm sharing my code with you.
The function in `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

def Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = file('/etc/profile.d/my_proj.properties')   //pay attention to the path
def opencvRoot;
if (propFile.canRead()){
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))
    println(props)

    if (props!=null && props.containsKey('OPENCVROOT')) {
        opencvRoot = props['OPENCVROOT']
        println("opencvRoot = ${opencvRoot}")
    }else{
        println("Doesn't contains opencvRoot = ${opencvRoot}")
    }
}else{
    println("I can't read opencvRoot = ${opencvRoot}")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion versionCompiler
    buildToolsVersion versionBuildTool

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion versionTarget
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments "OPENCV_ROOT:=${opencvRoot}"
            }
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
}
```

The `Android.mk` file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#opencv
OPENCVROOT := $(OPENCV_ROOT) # This doesn't work
# OPENCVROOT:= /home/username/OpenCV-android-sdk

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

I would really appreciate any help !

Comment: I know this is an old post, but have you ever solved this?

Comment: Not yet !! Even now I cannot figure out how to do this. Any help will be greatly appreciate. We (my team and I) had to set default path in the Android.mk file, so anyone can change the contain according to his configuration but are not allow to push the file.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out, hopefully this will help you or anyone else with a similar problem.

I added this to the end of my `build.gradle`:

```
task ndkBuildCompile(type:Exec) {
    commandLine("${project.ext.ndk_dir}${File.separator}ndk-build",
                "OPENCVROOT=${opencvRoot}")
}
```

Then in `Android.mk` I can reference it like normal, like so:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

# This now WORKS
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting it in `/etc/profile.d/my_proj.sh` should work. Did you try to logout and login?

I am setting my OPENCVROOT in `~/.profile` and it is visible inside `Android.mk` for gradle and ndk-build.
Just remember **not** to set it in `~/.bashrc` which is only for terminal subshells not programs started from GUI which Android Studio often is.

Answer (score 1):

As i realized, my approach is same like yours. Sharing the variables with Android.mk is possible by passing as arguments while describing configurations. You should ensure that **opencvRoot** variable is as expected.
In build.gradle

```
android{  
   defaultConfig   {  
      externalNativeBuild      {  
         ndkBuild         {  
            arguments "GRADLETESTVARIABLE="+buildEmulator
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In Android.mk

```
ifeq ($(GRADLETESTVARIABLE),true)
TEST_VARIABLE:=$(GRADLETESTVARIABLE)
$(error the error is f $(TEST_VARIABLE))
else
TEST_VARIABLE:=$(GRADLETESTVARIABLE)
$(error the error is l $(TEST_VARIABLE))
endif
```