# Add the Android SDK path to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio

I have an Android SDK which I keep updated with the tools and platforms that I need,I recently felt that it was time to migrate to Google's new Android Studio IDE after Eclipse destroyed my workspace for the zillionth time,instead of unzipping Eclipse I downloaded and installed Android Studio and tried to import a project,it looks like the IDE comes with an SDK of it's own.I would like to add path to my SDK folder and my NDK folder as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got SDK manager just as in ADT. It didn't let me change the SDK directory, though.

So, go to "Project Structure" menu (or "Other Settings/Default Project Structure"), and set the home path for Android SDK. here is [a bit outdated tutorial](http://techglimpse.com/solution-fix-android-sdk-studio-error/): the GUI has changed since v.0.1, but the substance is still completely relevant.

A week ago, v.0.4 preview has been released - maybe the menus have been shuffled a bit again, I don't know.

PS: note that NDK integration is still not official, but some workarounds have been accumulated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667903/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk).