# Eclipse to Android Studio Migration

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a project which I developed in Eclipse. Now I want to migrate it to Android Studio and when i try to compile (in Android Studio) the build fails and it says:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
> Failed to seal APK

And thus it doesn't compile. I have literally no experience with Android studio and i tried my best to follow the "tutorial" for migrating, but I'm stuck here so I dont know what else to do.

Comment: What is your JDK version?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_31"

Comment: Do you have any JNI libs in your project, or anything to do with the NDK?

Comment: Actually, there's a Lib on my project called "armeabi" and it's listed under a jniLibs folder.

Comment: You might need to add the `jniLibs` folder to your `build.gradle` as a source set manually similarly to how it is done here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26693354/2413303 ( `jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs` )

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one by one and see if it works

1. Remove  ~/.gradle. files and re-open using Android studio and download gradle if it asks while reopening ..it might solve the problem
2. Change the JDK vesion used by Android studio

   follow [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827547-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)
3. add the following to build.gradle and try

   compileOptions 
      {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
   }

Comment: You mean files in a folder called "gradle"?

Comment: yes and there is a hidden directory called .gradle clear that too

Comment: Should i delete the hidden directory or both (visible/hidden)?

Comment: First try the option 3 and let me know

Comment: I need to know if I have to delete the gradle folder files that's on the Android Studio folder OR the hidden one..

Comment: Try hidden one...But my suggestion is try the option 3 and see if it works

Comment: If i add the compileOptions line it says "Gradle DSL method not found: compileOptions".

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea - In that case try other options. But..did you restart android studio and tried clean and build ?

Comment: Tried deleting hidden and visible gradle ?

Comment: Where's the hidden folder?

Comment: In Mac os you can see by doing  ls -a in terminal