# Android Studio Gradle build: NDK error

Tags: gradle, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I am trying to run this project: https://github.com/uday-rayala/video-trimmer, but I got this error:

> Error:(199) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I use Android Studio 1.3.1, gradle 2.8 on Mac.
Please anyone guides me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Eclipse project, you must import it into Android Studio, and I believe that you performed this step correctly with the help of the import wizard.

But to build the native (NDK) part for this project, you cannot use the Android Studio NDK support. You should enable `ndk-build` and disable the `compile*Ndk` tasks in your **build.gradle** script, as described in *[JNI and Gradle in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26693354/192373)*.

Comment: Oh. I already built it successfully. I fixed it by adding this code: sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        //disable automatic ndk-build call
        jni.srcDirs = []

    } but now it runs with blank screen in device. Now I try to use FFMpeg insteads.

Comment: Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I never try it before... how can I do that. Please show me.