# SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs Fatal signal 11 when using x86 native library

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlcipher

I have a working Android app that uses the `armeabi` libraries for SQLCipher but I cannot make the app work for `x86`.

When I try and debug the app on an x86 device I can step through the app until the call to `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);` which results in `A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)`

I've checked the library loading in logcat;

**armeabi**

```
D/dalvikvm? Trying to load lib /data/data/com.eglootech.sqlcipher/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x42562c10
D/dalvikvm? Added shared lib /data/data/com.eglootech.sqlcipher/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x42562c10
D/dalvikvm? No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.eglootech.sqlcipher/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x42562c10, skipping init
D/dalvikvm? Trying to load lib /data/data/com.eglootech.sqlcipher/lib/libsqlcipher_android.so 0x42562c10
D/dalvikvm? Added shared lib /data/data/com.eglootech.sqlcipher/lib/libsqlcipher_android.so 0x42562c10
D/dalvikvm? No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.eglootech.sqlcipher/lib/libsqlcipher_android.so 0x42562c10, skipping init
D/dalvikvm? Trying to load lib /data/data/com.eglootech.sqlcipher/lib/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so 0x42562c10
D/dalvikvm? Added shared lib /data/data/com.eglootech.sqlcipher/lib/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so 0x42562c10
I/Database? JNI_OnLoad called
I/Database? JNI_OnLoad register methods
```

**x86**

```
D/dalvikvm? Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.eglootech.electorlookup-2/libstlport_shared.so 0x41c3e430
D/dalvikvm? Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.eglootech.electorlookup-2/libstlport_shared.so 0x41c3e430
D/dalvikvm? No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.eglootech.electorlookup-2/libstlport_shared.so 0x41c3e430, skipping init
D/dalvikvm? Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.eglootech.electorlookup-2/libsqlcipher_android.so 0x41c3e430
D/dalvikvm? Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.eglootech.electorlookup-2/libsqlcipher_android.so 0x41c3e430
D/dalvikvm? No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.eglootech.electorlookup-2/libsqlcipher_android.so 0x41c3e430, skipping init
D/dalvikvm? Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.eglootech.electorlookup-2/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so 0x41c3e430
D/dalvikvm? Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.eglootech.electorlookup-2/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so 0x41c3e430
A/libc? Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 2313 (h.electorlookup)
```

Why would the `JNI_OnLoad` calls be missing?

I can step into the I can step into the the call to the `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);` and the error comes from `SQLiteDatabase` and the call to `loadLibs(android.content.Context context, java.io.File workingDir)` where `workingDir` is `/data/data/com.eglootech.sqlcipher/files`.

I have included both the `armeabi` and `x86` native libraries in the same way within my Android Studio project;

[image: libs folder with armeabi and x86]

These are the binaries you download from SQLCipher and then each platform directory is zipped under a `lib` folder and then the zip renamed to `.jar`. They appear in the list as `lib.armeabi` and `lib.x86` although they are nested folders within the `.jar`.

Then in Gradle I have the following that should make sure the native files are copied across;

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Is there a reason the native libraries would not be included for `x86`?

I have also tried including the libraries not in a `.jar` and just in a directory according to; [Android studio, gradle and NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667903/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk/16790675#16790675)

Again the app works in `armeabi` but not `x86`.

The app can work on `x86` with just the `armeabi` libraries but the performance suffers because of the virtualisation and we want to prove with the correct native libraries `x86` performs as well if not better.

Comment: I have provided additional questions regarding your situation on the SQLCipher mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlcipher/LbU-wuvrwHU/e-rLS0DIX24J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original problem was due to the structure of the `.jar` folder and it not locating the correct native library. The native libraries needed to be in a single `.jar` file.

The latest version of [SQLCipher for Android](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/) is distributed via an AAR package, integration within Gradle can be performed by adding the following to the `app/build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar'
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
}
```