# Android unittest googletest

Tags: android, c++, unit-testing, android-ndk, googletest

I use Android Studio to build simple application with c++ support. Now I want to write unittest for functions in my native lib. How can I include google test in my CMakeLists.txt to build and run my tests on Android device?

When I put

```
enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(foo foo.cc)
target_link_libraries(foo ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES})
add_test(AllTestsInFoo foo)
```

in CMakeLists.txt I've go an error that GTest is not found.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667903/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972639/android-studio-with-ndk-and-googletest) questions. And the [documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/sources/third_party/googletest/README.NDK?autodive=0%2F), but they all are about .mk files not about CMakeLists.txt

How should I find googletest library on android device and link my test project with it?

Maybe i should write my own CMakeLists.txt for sourses located in

```
${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/third_party/googletest
```

to apply paches and build this library by myself?