# Breakpoints in native code can not be triggered in Android Studio 13

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

Following the [Android NDK Preview](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview) document, I install android-ndk-10e and experimental gradle plugin ,import the [Teapot](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/Teapot) sample project then set the "Android Native".

Things seem works fine except that the breakpoints in native code can not be triggered. Have tested on OS X Yosemite and Windows 7, both failed.

Here is a [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/r4q67-JKBPM) says doing some changes to gradle file, but not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate "Android Native" Run configuration:

`Run > Edit Configurations > + > Android Native`

Comment: new "Android Native" instead of using the "Android Native" in "Default", works, thanks you!