# Gradle build failed : Error:Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.ExtensibleDynamicObject

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio-2.0

Hello I have get Gradle build failed error and i am using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897504/gradle-build-errorcause-org-gradle-api-internal-extensibledynamicobject) is useful for me but still getting same error so can't understand what's the problems.

***Following are my code of gradle.build file.***

**My App:build.gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
```

model {

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "com.atreyainnovations.optographlocal"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 14
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        multiDexEnabled = true
        /*versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"*/

    }
}

android.ndk {
    moduleName = "add-jni"
    toochain = "clang"
}

android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
        // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        //proguardFiles + file('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
```

}

**library:build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'
```

model {

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig.with {
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 14
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
}

android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
    }
}
```

}

Comment: After hour of time I spending on this stuff I'll downgrade my android studio 2.0 to 1.5 and now I'll run my c code. But don't know what's the problem on android studio 2.0