# Error:Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.ExtensibleDynamicObject

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to use NDK in Android Studio, but an error occurs:
**Error:Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.ExtensibleDynamicObject**
My Android Studio version is 2.2 preview 1, and Gradle version is 2.10.
gradle-experimental version is 0.7.0
I have tryed this [Gradle build Error:Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.ExtensibleDynamicObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897504/gradle-build-errorcause-org-gradle-api-internal-extensibledynamicobject)  but it did not work.
Anyone knows how to resolve it?

Here are my build.gradle file contents:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.stupideme.shuclass"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    android.ndk {
        moduleName "ndktest"
        ldLibs.addAll(['log'])
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        platformVersion 16
        stl 'gnustl_shared'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFiles  += file('proguard-rules.pro')

        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'io.github.yavski:fab-speed-dial:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.akashandroid90:imageletter:1.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        proguardFiles  += file('proguard-rules.pro')
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
minSdkVersion.apiLevel 16
targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 21
```

instead of

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 21
```

and

```
moduleName = 'ndktest'
```

instead of

```
moduleName "ndktest"
```

it should be

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "me.stupideme.shuclass"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }


        android.ndk {
            moduleName = 'ndktest'
            ldLibs.addAll(['log'])
            cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
            cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
            platformVersion 16
            stl 'gnustl_shared'
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')

            }
        }
        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
            compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
            compile 'io.github.yavski:fab-speed-dial:1.0.1'
            compile 'com.github.akashandroid90:imageletter:1.5'
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
            androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
            androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
            }
        }
    }
}
```