# Including external C++ libraries and native NDK support in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I am trying to make use of the (experimental) native NDK support in Android Studio. I am new to working with Gradle. The project I am trying to build uses outside libraries which are to be compiled as static libraries when compiling the project and then be used within it. How can I do this?

To elaborate - There is C++ code in the default `src/main/jni`, it compiles properly and it can be seen properly in Android Studio under the `jni` folder. The project uses external C++ static libraries - some are compiled, some not. I need the project and the libraries to be built correctly and the code t obe visible where possible.

First of all, is there a way to be able to use Android.mk files? They are already available from a previous scheme to import the libraries but it seems that they are ignored now.

I've tried using `srcDirs` in `android.source` to add the libraries' paths and it works up to some point but strangely some of the paths are not found from the compiler and the compilation stops. Here's the code:

```
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDirs += ["/../../../libPdf/"]

//                  aes library
                    srcDirs += ["/../../../libs/aes/include", "/../../../libs/aes"]

//                  jpeg library
                    srcDirs += ["/../../../libPdf/platform/Android", "/../../../libs/jpeg/jpeg-9"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've also tried adding the libraries as separate modules and then compiling each one of them in the project `build.gradle` (I saw this one in this sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-thirdparty) but I get this error even if I create a `build.gradle` file for the library:

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

I don't know if I need an .iml file for the library, I don't have one and I don't know how to create one. I tried altering an existing one an putting it in the library but the same error occurred.
Here is the code from the project's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

def jpeg_sdk_path = file(project(':jpeg').projectDir).absolutePath + "/jpeg-9"

model {

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            consumerProguardFiles += file('proguard-project.txt')
        }
    }


    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "native"

        cppFlags += "-I${jpeg_sdk_path}".toString()
        ldLibs += ["jpeg"]

    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 14
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }


        lintOptions.with {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
        }

        //copy resources and stuff tasks

    }


}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
    compile project(':jpeg')
}
```

And here is the settings.gradle:

```
include ':libPDF'
include ':PDFViewer'
include ':jpeg'
project(':jpeg').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '/../../../libs/jpeg')
```

There are more libraries to be included but I am trying to import just one for now - jpeg, to see that it is working. I am trying to make local modules now and somehow connect them from gradle to the code which is elsewhere. I still get the same error - the `build.gradle` file does not seem to be found.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I managed to get the whole thing compiled but now I get linker errors. Here's the (shortened version of) build.gradle of the project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

def jpeg_sdk_path = file(project(':jpeg').projectDir).absolutePath + "/../../../../../../../libs/jpeg/jpeg-9"
//other defs of paths

model {

android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        consumerProguardFiles += file('proguard-project.txt')
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled = false
        consumerProguardFiles += file('proguard-project.txt')
    }
}

android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs += ["src/main/jni/"]
                //lcms2
                srcDirs += [lcms2_out_path + "/src"]


                //freetype library
                include aes_path + "/aes_modes.c"
                include aes_path + "/aescrypt.c"
                include aes_path + "/aeskey.c"
                include aes_path + "/aestab.c"

 //                  jbig2 library
                srcDirs += [jbig2_path + "/src/jbig2", jbig2_path + "/include"]

//                  sfntly library
                include sfntly_path + "/sample/chromium/subsetter_impl.cc"
                //many other includes here

//                  jpeg library
                srcDirs += [ jpeg_main_path + "/../../../../../../../libPdf/platform/Android"]

                include jpeg_sdk_path + "/jaricom.c"
                include jpeg_sdk_path + "/jcapimin.c"
                //many other includes here

                //native libpdf library
                include libpdf_path+ "/PdfCatalog.cpp"
                //many other includes here

                //openssl library
                srcDirs += [openssl_path + "/lib/Android/armeabi-v7a/include"]
            }
        }

        jniLibs{
            source{
                srcDirs += ['/src/main/libs']
                srcDirs += [freetype_path + '/platform/Android/obj/local']
                srcDirs += [libpdf_path]
            }
        }

        resources.source.srcDirs += ['src/main/res']
    }


}

android.ndk {
    moduleName = "native"

    CFlags += "-I${openjpeg_path}/prebuilt/armeabi-v7a/include".toString() //figure out how to include for other flavors
    CFlags += "-I${jpeg_main_path}/../../../../../../../libPdf/platform/Android".toString()
    CFlags += "-I${jpeg_sdk_path}".toString()
    //other CFlags here
    CFlags += "-DSFNTLY_NO_EXCEPTION"
    CFlags += "-DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION"
    cppFlags += CFlags

    abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
    ldFlags += "-L${freetype_src_path }/../platform/Android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a".toString()
    ldLibs += ["log", "android", "EGL", "GLESv1_CM", "ft2"]
    //other ldFlags and ldLibs - for the static .a libraries only
    stl = "gnustl_static"

}

compileOptions.with {
    sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig.with {
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 14
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
    }

    lintOptions.with {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        abortOnError = false
    }

    //tasks for moving resources and stuff here
}
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
compile project(':jpeg')
compile project(':freetype')
compile project(':lcms2')
compile project(':jbig2')
compile project(':aes')
compile project(':openjpeg')
compile project(':sfntly')
}
```

Now I get a lot of errors like that:

> Error:(737, -1) Gradle: undefined reference to 'AndroidBitmap_getInfo'

I think I know why I get this - I should use something else instead of `include` to add individual files to the source set.

My question now is: **How do I add individual files to a source set so they can be used by the compiler and later by the linker?**

Comment: The issue is not clear. in which module do you have the error?Which is the configuration with the error?

Comment: The module is 'jpeg' - it is empty, the only row of code is 'apply plugin: "java"'. I created a new native configuration and I am using it (just like in the official tutorial). Anyway, I got the compilation working. I have linker problems. I will update the question shortly. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Documentation explicitly says that "pure native" modules are not supported *(yet?)*

Comment: for me, `include` statements inside `main.jni.sources` have no effect

Comment: I prefer to use the traditional **Android.mk** approach, today it is still much more flexible and supported. The trick is to disable the built-in gradle compile and link tasks, and add a manual `buildNative` task.

Comment: Actually, **Android.mk** was the previous approach which I am trying to migrate from because we want to debug both C++ and Java code from Android Studio. Do you know if `include` is the proper way to add a single file but it's just not supported (for now?) in `main.jni.sources`? I moved some files around and without using `include` the app compiled and executed. But now Android Studio won't recognize and connect the native declarations in Java with the C++ functions... So debugging works only for Java and I'm screwed again...

Comment: Also, what does _pure native modules_ actually mean? My modules' gradle files are all empty with applied java plugin. I think all of this could be done without them but I wanted to move the declarations of native code source paths in each module once I had had success in debugging without the modules.

Comment: *Pure native* is a module without Java sources, e.g. based on NativeActivity. Actually, there seem to still be problems with library modules that have native code (their AAR is not *exploded* as expected). Please check the hybrid solution I proposed for *[define LOCAL_SRC_FILES in ndk{} DSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636150/define-local-src-files-in-ndk-dsl/32640823#32640823)*.

Comment: add ldLibs.add("jnigraphics") it will solve your linker problem

Comment: This is also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27737154/992509