# Native dev with Android Studio - Getting the experimental Gradle 2.5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I've been searching the web for a download link to the 2.5 version of Gradle which supports the NDK in android applications, but i can't find any.

Is there an option in Android Studio to download it automatically like it is possible to do with the NDK ? Or is there a download link somewhere with some installation instructions ?

Thank you !

Comment: Also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27737154/992509 - covers how to get the experimental plugin and how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle Distributions:

https://services.gradle.org/distributions

Experimental Plugin User Guide:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for. Hoever i already read that page you linked, and unless i missed something, it doesn't explain how to install Gradle. Should i extract the downloaded zip into the Gradle folder of my android studio installation ? Thank you.

Comment: I found it thank you. Just had to extract the grade-2.7 folder and place it into `...Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.7`, i think...