# After updating to Android Studio 2.0 from 1.5, ndk syntax highlighting not working or might be broken

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Syntax highlighting for C/C++ code in editor window was working fine in AS 1.5.

But after updating from AS 1.5 to 2.0, its not working even with sample HelloJNI project.

Tried with saved settings, reset default settings and also with fresh download and install of AS 2.0 but nothing worked.

Using Gradle 2.10 distribution with Gradle dependency gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing same issue and I have found out its a bug. More info can be found here:

[Android Studio cannot find jni.h, but compilation still works.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195483)

[Android Studio (2.0 beta 2)'s inline compiler does no longer recognize my native code](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200800)

The compilation and debugging still works, this is just visual issue. I hope they fix it soon.

Comment: Seems like they have fixed this issue in AS 0.7.0-rc1 see this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195483 Can anyone provide some fix for AS stable version, I cannot work on nightly builds.